# Keeping the soft keyboard open while the user transitions from one view to another

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, wizard

I'm new to Android, and I want to create a user account registration wizard. The wizard will have several steps. At each step, there is an input field where the user has to enter in their information. What I'd like to do is to keep the soft keyboard open while the user transitions from one step to another step. What kind of UI widget can I use to achieve this? Ideally, I'd like to avoid creating separate `Activity` or `Fragment` instances.

[image]

Basically I have the following requirements:

- The wizard contains multiple steps.
- Each step has an `EditText`.
- As the user transitions back and forth between steps, the soft keyboard **must** stay open.

Comment: It can be a Fragment/Activity which has a ViewPager / RecyclerView containing different EditTexts for each item (top section).

Comment: "Each step has an EditText" -- what else is there in a step, besides the `EditText`? "As the user transitions back and forth between steps" -- what is your definition of "transition"? Ignoring your soft keyboard concerns for the moment, what is the expected UX of such a transition?

Comment: Transition happens when the user hits the "Next" button on the keyboard. Transition means moving from one step to another. Both the current and the new steps will slide from right to left during the transitioning phase. Besides the `EditText`, there will be `TextViews` above and below each entry field.

Answer (score 0):

The keyboard will stay up as long as a view that takes keyboard input (where getInputConnection returns non-null) has focus.  So make the root view focusable and take a input.  Focus it before you transition.  Transition.  Then focus the new edit text.  That should work.  (Note:  have not tried, but by the rules of keyboards it ought to work).